# can I see the code block as a parameter for the iterator method(each/...)?

Tags: ruby, codeblocks

I am new in ruby and I am confused with  the code bock and the parameter.

For example:

```
"This@is@a @tring".split("@")
```

In this code,the "This is a string" is an **String** object,and the **split** is a method of string object,and the "@" is the parameter for the **split** method.

This is really clear since it is the same with other programe language.

However when I see the code block:

```
[1,2,3].each {|data| puts data}
```

The [1,2,3] is an **array** object,the **each** is one of its method(right?).

for the code block here:

```
{|data| puts data}
```

I understand it as a Anonymous function,in javascript,it maybe like this :

```
function(data){ puts data}
```

So I think may be I can use the code block as the parameter of the **each** method. So I try this:

```
[1,2,3].each ({|data| puts data})
```

I just add the brace,but it show me some errors.

Why?

Can anyone tell me more about the code block in ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block is a special part of Ruby syntax. Unlike most things in Ruby, it is not an object, nor is it an argument of the function in the normal sense: methods can only accept one block, and it must come after the argument list. So, in your final example, the parentheses represent the argument list. Putting the block inside that list violates Ruby syntax.

If you're interested in essentially passing around blocks, however, you kinda can. Take a look at the `Proc` class, which is kinda like a proxy object for blocks. When a `Proc` object is created, it accepts a block parameter. The `#call` method on a `Proc` passes its arguments to that block.

```
print_twice = Proc.new { |x| puts x; puts x }
print_twice.call(1) # prints 1 twice
print_twice.call(2) # prints 2 twice
print_twice.call(3) # prints 3 twice
```

Additionally, with a special syntax, a `Proc` can be used as a method call's block:

```
print_twice = Proc.new { |x| puts x; puts x }
[1, 2, 3].each(&print_twice)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
[1, 2, 3].each { |x| puts x; puts x }
```

The `&print_twice` as the final argument of `each` essentially passes it as the block. And, since `print_twice` is its own object, you can pass it to as many methods as you like.

Hope this helps a bit! :)

Comment: So,except the syntax,is my understanding right?  The code bock canbe seen as a function?

Comment: Yes, your analogy with JavaScript is exactly correct. Except in Ruby, a block used in a method call isn't usually an argument.

Comment: @hguser: pretty much. The big difference is that, in Javascript, a  function is an object that can be stored to a variable. A block is not, so we need to use the `Proc` object as a wrapper of sorts if we need to pass a block around.

Answer (score 0):

[- Official doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html)

[- Maybe a better explanation](http://blog.excastle.com/2005/05/18/ruby-coolness-1-blocks/)